# Jupyter for WebSocket communication

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working on an app which needs to have a WebSockets API, and will also integrate Jupyter (former IPython) notebooks as a relatively minor feature. Since Jupyter already uses WebSockets for communication, how difficult it would be to integrate it as a general library for serving other WebSockets APIs apart to its own? Or am I better off using another library such as `aiohttp`? I'm looking for any advice and hints abut the best practices for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proxy WebSockets from your main application to Jupyter.

It really doesn't matter what technology you use to serve WebSockets, the proxy loop will be very similar (wait for message, push message forward). However, it will be web server dependent as Python does not have standard to WebSockets akin WSGI.

I did one in [pyramid_notebook project](https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/pyramid_notebook). Running Jupyter in its own process is must as, at least by the time of writing the code, embedding Jupyter directly to your application was not feasible. I am not sure though if the latest version have changed this. Jupyter itself was using Tornado.

```
"""UWSGI websocket proxy."""
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
import logging
import time

import uwsgi
from pyramid import httpexceptions
from ws4py import WS_VERSION
from ws4py.client import WebSocketBaseClient


#: HTTP headers we need to proxy to upstream websocket server when the Connect: upgrade is performed
CAPTURE_CONNECT_HEADERS = ["sec-websocket-extensions", "sec-websocket-key", "origin"]


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ProxyClient(WebSocketBaseClient):
    """Proxy between upstream WebSocket server and downstream UWSGI."""

    @property
    def handshake_headers(self):
        """
        List of headers appropriate for the upgrade
        handshake.
        """
        headers = [
            ('Host', self.host),
            ('Connection', 'Upgrade'),
            ('Upgrade', 'WebSocket'),
            ('Sec-WebSocket-Key', self.key.decode('utf-8')),
            # Origin is proxyed from the downstream server, don't set it twice
            # ('Origin', self.url),
            ('Sec-WebSocket-Version', str(max(WS_VERSION)))
            ]

        if self.protocols:
            headers.append(('Sec-WebSocket-Protocol', ','.join(self.protocols)))

        if self.extra_headers:
            headers.extend(self.extra_headers)

        logger.info("Handshake headers: %s", headers)
        return headers

    def received_message(self, m):
        """Push upstream messages to downstream."""

        # TODO: No support for binary messages
        m = str(m)
        logger.debug("Incoming upstream WS: %s", m)
        uwsgi.websocket_send(m)
        logger.debug("Send ok")

    def handshake_ok(self):
        """
        Called when the upgrade handshake has completed
        successfully.

        Starts the client's thread.
        """
        self.run()

    def terminate(self):
        super(ProxyClient, self).terminate()

    def run(self):
        """Combine async uwsgi message loop with ws4py message loop.

        TODO: This could do some serious optimizations and behave asynchronously correct instead of just sleep().
        """

        self.sock.setblocking(False)
        try:
            while not self.terminated:
                logger.debug("Doing nothing")
                time.sleep(0.050)

                logger.debug("Asking for downstream msg")
                msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv_nb()
                if msg:
                    logger.debug("Incoming downstream WS: %s", msg)
                    self.send(msg)

                s = self.stream

                self.opened()

                logger.debug("Asking for upstream msg")
                try:
                    bytes = self.sock.recv(self.reading_buffer_size)
                    if bytes:
                        self.process(bytes)
                except BlockingIOError:
                    pass

        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
        finally:
            logger.info("Terminating WS proxy loop")
            self.terminate()


def serve_websocket(request, port):
    """Start UWSGI websocket loop and proxy."""
    env = request.environ

    # Send HTTP response 101 Switch Protocol downstream
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'], env.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', ''))

    # Map the websocket URL to the upstream localhost:4000x Notebook instance
    parts = urlparse(request.url)
    parts = parts._replace(scheme="ws", netloc="localhost:{}".format(port))
    url = urlunparse(parts)

    # Proxy initial connection headers
    headers = [(header, value) for header, value in request.headers.items() if header.lower() in CAPTURE_CONNECT_HEADERS]

    logger.info("Connecting to upstream websockets: %s, headers: %s", url, headers)

    ws = ProxyClient(url, headers=headers)
    ws.connect()

    # TODO: Will complain loudly about already send headers - how to abort?
    return httpexceptions.HTTPOk()
```

Comment: Hi Mikko, thank you for your answer. In fact, after some digging I have realised that my question was not what I really wanted to ask. So I'm mostly curious about any experience in reusing iPython's `comm` objects for communication with the front-end in an external app. That being said, your answer was still quite useful and provided answers to other questions that popped up in the process, so I'll accept it and create a new question.